# Deploying my Django website to Heroku with DEBUG=False doesn't work

Tags: python, django, heroku, http-status-code-500

When deploying django onto either localhost or heroku with DEBUG=False, it throws an error saying

```
C:\Users\krish\Envs\PRREMIA\lib\site-packages\whitenoise\base.py:105: UserWarning: No directory at: c:\Users\krish\Documents\python\PRREMIA\staticfiles\
  warnings.warn(u'No directory at: {}'.format(root))
[28/Jul/2019 16:05:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 27
```

When DEBUG=True, it works fine.

STATIC SETTINGS

```py
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

On [Github](https://github.com/PRREMIA/prremia-django)

Why? And how do I stop and fix this?

**Note:**
Removing whitenose middleware from `MIDDLEWARE` and changing `STATICFILES_STORAGE`

```py
# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
```

removed the 500 Error, but the staticfiles are still not found.

Comment: Whitenoise deals with static files. So show your STATIC settings.

Comment: Heroku should never show anything with `C:\ ` in it. That's a Windows-style path, and Heroku doesn't run Windows. Are you including absolute paths anywhere in your settings?

Comment: @Chris No, I've been use forward slashes everywhere. (Honestly, I didn't know that Windows used back slashes instead until a couple months ago). You can also check out my [code](https://github.com/PRREMIA/prremia-django)

Comment: You should check that you can run `python manage.py collectstatic` locally without any errors. If Heroku can't run that successfully when compiling your project than staticfiles won't work.

Comment: @12944qwerty, it's not just the backslash. It's the `C:` itself, and the reference to a Windows path that appears to point at a local virtual environment: `C:\Users\krish\Envs\PRREMIA`. Something in your code is referencing a local path.

Comment: @Chris I still didn't use `C:` anywhere either.

Comment: @D.Evans When running `collectstatic` locally, it created a whole directory called `staticfiles` with `admin` and `business` in it. See [here](https://i.imgur.com/zQs3vR3.png)

Comment: @D.Evans When running the command on heroku, it throws this [error (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/raw/VWt6LQ3b)

Comment: Also, `staticfiles` is found in the root directory of the project

Comment: @Chris So, after a little messing around, I found that `BASE_DIR` includes `C:`. Is the fine?

Comment: So, I changed my question a little different because I found a fix to this question but not completely.

Answer (score 1):

## Configure Django / Create-React-App / Whitenoise to run git deploy to Heroku App with DEBUG = False

Big thank-you to Whitenoise developers first off to make this all possible!

In your settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },

    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static'),     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

In views.py create a template view of index.html

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

# Serve Single Page Application
index = never_cache(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
```

In urls.py add path to your new view

```
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from .views import index

urlpatterns += [
    re_path('.*', index)
]
```

Run `npm run build` and then `python manage.py collectstatic` before pushing to heroku.  This will build your application into a build folder, and then collect these static build files into a staticfiles folder in your project root.

If `python manage.py collectstatic` fails, create an empty directory called staticfiles in the project root first.

The point of the index re_path view is to always point your application back to index.html when reloading a page at a path like '/login'.

```
git add .
git commit -m "blah"
git push heroku master
```

This worked for me, hopefully it helps people somewhat in the future.

If this does not work, my advice is to investigate by running `python manage.py runserver` locally and messing around with your build folder, staticfiles folder, and settings.py to figure out what is going on.  I would also recommend logging to find the error, although I did not do this myself.

Answer (score 0):

Your STATICFILES_DIRS setting is incorrect:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

This refers to a directory called `static` in the root of your project, but there is no such directory.

It looks like your static files are inside the `business` application, in which case they will be picked up automatically so you can just remove the `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting altogether.

Comment: You've just rewritten your question to be about something different. This isn't a great idea as now none of the comments or answers will make sense to someone looking at this in future.

Comment: Ok, but I just tried your suggestion, and unfortunately, it didn't work.. :(